# How to translate 狂拽炫酷吊炸天 to English?

Tags: translation, internet-slang

I know it's an internet slang and meme, the rough meaning is “particularly cool”, however, how to properly translate it with especially **equal rhetorical level**? Here's some context:

- 原来天地决那**狂拽炫酷吊炸天**的特效是个npc的模型！
- 这舞台效果简直**吊炸天**啊，换装怎么弄的？ (A briefer variant of 狂拽炫酷吊炸天 is used here)
- 今天就带大家看看那些农村刷墙的神文案，真是**狂拽炫酷吊炸天**！所谓接地气的好广告，就该这样简单粗暴。
- 感觉这几年Kpop一直在追求**狂拽炫酷吊炸天**的风格，初听很洗脑，但热度过去了就很少会去点来听了。

[Reference from Baidu Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%90%8A%E7%82%B8%E5%A4%A9/5368748)

Comment: a simple "awesome" would do.

Comment: In the fourth sentence, it seems to be used in an *very implicitly* pejorative sense, referring to (Kpop) the *overly deliberate* pursuit of glamour and excellence which backfires, “awesome” sounds not a well fit in this context.

Answer (score 2):

"Badass" should do the job for you here.

Answer (score 0):

It means "super fucking cool".

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the mind-blowingly awesome special effects in "Heaven and Earth" were just an NPC's model!

These stage effects are insanely cool! How did they manage the costume changes?

Today, let's take a look at those epic rural wall slogans. They're absolutely amazing! A true down-to-earth ad should be as straightforward and bold as these.

It seems like Kpop has been pursuing this over-the-top cool style in recent years. It's catchy at first, but once the hype dies down, I rarely go back to listen.